# PDF generated with TCPDF showing up fine in Adobe Acrobat but corrupted in Illustrator

Tags: fonts, tcpdf

Using TCPDF 6.3.5

I'm currently facing an issue where where pdf files fonts show up correctly in Acrobat Pro but if I try to open the same file in illustrator the text is corrupt.

The fonts look like they have been correctly embedded by TCPDF in Acrobat see [screenshot from Acrobat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F6TW.png)

Opening the same file in illustrator the fonts look like this
[screen shot from illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzHjP.png)

Have tried:
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false)

This works fine, when I open it in illustrator all the characters are correct but it results with the pdf having a completely different font to what it's meant to be.